# Create duplicate values for missing Versions

Tags: sql, etl, snowflake-schema

I have a table as below

```
contact|version|col1|col2|col3
   1   |   1   |abc | 57 | X2
   4   |   4   |def | 59 | X3
   5   |   5   |xyz | 56 | X4
   7   |   7   |plo | 58 | X5
```

So I have version 1,4,5 and 7 but not versions 2,3 and 6. So for all the missing versions I want to create those versions by duplicating previous version values for all columns as below. I dont want any version number to be missing.

```
contact|version|col1|col2|col3
   1   |   1   |abc | 57 | X2
   1   |   2   |abc | 57 | X2
   1   |   3   |abc | 57 | X2
   4   |   4   |def | 59 | X3
   5   |   5   |xyz | 56 | X4
   5   |   6   |xyz | 56 | X4
   7   |   7   |plo | 58 | X5

Please suggest how can this be done.Appreciate in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - a list of integers left-joined to your in-data:

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in final query ..
indata(contact,version,col1,col2,col3) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'abc',57,'X2'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,4,'def',59,'X3'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,5,'xyz',56,'X4'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,7,'plo',58,'X5'
)
-- end of input - replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need a series of integers --
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 
  UNION ALL SELECT 9 
)
SELECT 
  NVL(contact,LAST_VALUE(contact IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY i)) AS contact
, i AS version
, NVL(col1,LAST_VALUE(col1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY i)) AS col1
, NVL(col2,LAST_VALUE(col2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY i)) AS col2
, NVL(col3,LAST_VALUE(col3 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY i)) AS col3
FROM i
LEFT JOIN indata ON version = i 
WHERE i <=(SELECT MAX(version) FROM indata);
;
-- out  contact | version | col1 | col2 | col3 
-- out ---------+---------+------+------+------
-- out        1 |       1 | abc  |   57 | X2
-- out        1 |       2 | abc  |   57 | X2
-- out        1 |       3 | abc  |   57 | X2
-- out        4 |       4 | def  |   59 | X3
-- out        5 |       5 | xyz  |   56 | X4
-- out        5 |       6 | xyz  |   56 | X4
-- out        7 |       7 | plo  |   58 | X5
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Hi I tried the query you provided but its returning different format than the one provided. I think its replacing all with 7 since we are taking i<= max(version)
```
-- out contact | version | col1 | col2 | col3 
-- out -------+---------+------+------+------
-- out      1 |       1 | abc  |   57 | X2
-- out      7 |       2 | plo  |   58 | X5
-- out      7 |       3 | plo  |   58 | X5
-- out      4 |       4 | def  |   59 | X3
-- out      5 |       5 | xyz  |   56 | X4
-- out      7 |       6 | plo  |   58 | X5
-- out      7 |       7 | plo  |   58 | X5
```